# How can I use project resources in my code?

Tags: java, resources

Say you are working on a project that involves using resources that were imported into your project in Eclipse.

In the `src` folder, you have a `res` folder, that contains all kinds of resources: Image files, WAV files.

Now obviously you need to access these files in your code. This should be trivial but I'm not sure how to do this.

What should I do? Somehow store the resource in a `File` object? Use some kind of stream?

**What is the best way to do this? The most common 'conventional' and/or simplest way you know to use resources in your code.**

Answer (score 0):

I use this packages to import this functionality for managing my media resources

```
javax.media.Format;
javax.media.Manager;
javax.media.MediaLocator;
javax.media.Player;
javax.media.PlugInManager;
javax.media.format.AudioFormat
```

;

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(newFile("/res/file.wav").toURI().toURL()));
```